# How to make ORelio Minecraft Console Client move player every 5 minutes

Tags: windows, command-line, batch, batch-file, minecraft

I'm using ORelio's Minecraft Console Client to bring my alternate accounts onto a server. I have written a windows batch file that can open the client, log into my account, and then connect to a designated server.

`start MinecraftClient.exe (Account email) (Account Password) (Server IP Address)`

From here I can manually type any commands I like into the client or just type to have my player speak in the server chat. The server has a 10 minute AFK timeout plugin. I can get around this by typing /move north, east, south, west, or up. I'm attempting to create a batch file that will both log the alt in, and every 5 minutes, loop the /move up command to make player jump and avoid logging them out. I've tried adding this to the .bat file but it seems to bring up a separate windows command that will count down from 10 and not do anything.

```
 type /move up 
 timeout /t 10 
 goto loop
```

I would appreciate any help with this as I've been working at this for awhile but am rather new at this so I have little knowledge/experience to go off of.

Comment: The issue is in the batch file, it doesn't know what to send your commands to. I would recommend using powershell and the sendkeys function. The script needs to know the window name to "activate" it and then send the inputs.

Comment: As I mentioned In incredibly new to this. If you don't mind, would you be able to provide me with the code I'd need to input into powershell to have this work? And is there not a way via batch files to specify the program to send the text to? If so how could I do this? Thank you.

Comment: Gave you somewhere to start below. Good luck

Answer (score 1):

I do not have minecraft, but it would be something similar to this. You can get the gist here and then google sendkeys and powershell to further nail down what you want to do.

```
#intiate your batch file to login with command above
Start-Process C:\Path\login.bat

$wshell = New-Object -ComObject wscript.shell;

#window title name goes here, assuming it is minecraft
$wshell.AppActivate('Minecraft')  

#begin infinite loop
while(1)
{
Sleep 5   #initiate a slight delay in the auto typing
$wshell.SendKeys('t')   #typing t brings up chat box

Sleep 5 #another delay to allow chat box to come up
$wshell.SendKeys('/move up')  #types slash move up

Sleep 5
$wshell.SendKeys('~')  #this is the symbol for sending the ENTER keystroke

Sleep 300   #sleeps the program and goes back to the top after the timer is over
}
```

Copy all of this and paste into notepad and save it as a .ps1 file. You will need to edit the path for your login.bat file and also ensure that the window name on the minecraft program is, in fact, minecraft.